# navigationController.navigationItem vs navigationItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

Just curious, why setting `self.navigationItem = ...` works, but `self.navigationController.navigationItem` fails? The same applies for `self.toolbarItems` vs `self.navigationController.toobarItems`.

When to use `self.navigationController.navigationItem`?

Maybe you will say, they point to different things. but why `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES` the navigation bar is hidden. doesn't it means `self.navigationController.navigationItem` point to the bar i wanted?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The class `UIViewController` has a property `navigationItem`.

This is true of all the subclasses too whether it is a `UICollectionViewController`, `UITableViewController`, `UINavigationViewController` or any custom subclass.

When presented by a `UINavigationController` the nav controller will create this property and so each view controller gets its own `navigationItem`.  If you do not present it from a navigation controller then the navigationItem is nil.

Now, with a `UINavigationController` you are more than likely using this as your initial view controller. Therefore, the navigation controller is NOT being presented by another navigation controller and its `navigationItem` property is nil.

The navigation bar is slightly different as this is managed the other way around.

Comment: does "the nav controller will create this property and so each view controller gets its own navigationItem" mean the `navigationItem` property can only be seted by parent? if this is true, why `self.navigationController.navigationItem` results to `<UINavigationItem: 0x8044020>` not nil?

Comment: after test, it turns out `self.navigationItem` won't be nil, cause after init, before added to navController `self.navigationItem` is seted.

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake. It is true though that the navigation item is owned by the currently visible controller not by the navigation controller.

Comment: Note Apple's docs: "The first time the property is accessed, the UINavigationItem object is created. Therefore, you should not access this property if you are not using a navigation controller to display the view controller"

Answer (score 0):

although set can set this property of a navigation controller: `self.navigationController.navigationItem = ..` but it won't work. 
Mainly because the navigationItem is a UIViewController's property. You can access the property because UINavigationController is inherited from UIViewController. this property is meant for any view controller that is added into a navigation controller to have a navigation bar created for them. Normally a UINavigationController won't be put into another navigation controller, so set this property of a navigation controller normally makes no sense.