# Create navigation item with default Icon programatically IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to create a navigation item "Refresh" with the default XCode refresh Icon programmatically. I know how to create one with the word "Refresh" with the following code. However, I want to have the icon insetead of the word "Refresh" Thanks for helping in advance

```
    let refreshButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Refresh", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(FollowVC.refresh))
```

[image: refresh]

Comment: Good question even already asked.

Comment: Check my updated answer for both objective c and swift.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Superb question.I tried sample one for your question.I got the solution and It works fine.

what you made mistake in your coding is

First your

```
let refreshButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Refresh", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(FollowVC.refresh))
```

is wrong.You have to use or write

```
UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem, target: AnyObject?, action:Selector)
```

Second you used **UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain**.If you want refresh button you have to set **UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh**.

**SWIFT**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    // Create the navigation bar
    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 64))) // set frame here

    //set the background color
    navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    navigationBar.delegate = self as? UINavigationBarDelegate;

    // Create a navigation item with a title
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "title" //If you want to set a tilte set here.Whatever you want set here.

    // Create  button for navigation item with refresh
    let refreshButton =  UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.refresh, target: self, action: Selector(("actionRefresh:")))


    // I set refreshButton for the navigation item
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refreshButton


    // Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

    // Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)

}

#pragma action method

func actionRefresh(sender: UIBarButtonItem) 
{
  print("The action button is refreshed")
}
```

Print statement is

```
The action button is refreshed
```

**OBJECTIVE C**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   UINavigationBar *navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64)];

   navbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];   

   navbar.delegate = self;
   UINavigationItem * navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];

   navItem.title = @"Title";  //Set Title Here Wahtever You Want Here
   UIBarButtonItem *buttonRefresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                           target:self
                           action:@selector(actionRefresh:)];

   navItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonRefresh;
   navbar.items = @[navItem];
   [self.view addSubview:navbar];
 }
```

The NSLog statement is

```
The button action refresh is performed
```

See the refresh button in screenshot

[image]

Good Solutions

[Add Default Icons to Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558014/ios-how-to-add-use-default-icons-to-navigation-bar-in-swift)

[Navigation Bar Item Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718004/changing-nav-bar-item-programmatically-in-swift)

[Adding Navigation Bar item Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448766/adding-navigation-bar-programmatically-ios)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `.Plain`, you should be using `.Refresh`.

`let refreshButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Refresh, target: self, action: #selector(FollowVC.refresh))`

Also you should be using the `init(barButtonSystemItem:target:action:)` instead of the `init(title:style:target:action:)`.