# why there is a navigationItem in the UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am reading about `UINavigationController`, and it makes sense to have a navigationItem in the `NavigationController`,

but when I create a `UIViewController`, there is also a property called `navigationItem` from type `UINavigationItem`

so now I have :

1. navigationItem in the `UIViewController`
2. navigationItem in the `UINavigationController`

do they have different purposes ?

It sounds like the navigationItem in the `UINavigationController` is not working because I did this code in a `UIViewController`:

```
self.navigationController!.navigationItem.title = "test2"
```

and the title didn't change, while I did this code:

```
 self.navigationItem.title = "test"
```

and the title changed

Comment: what is your query in your questions?

Comment: if u don't have navigation item or bar in Uiviewcontroller where you would add buttons and other things while your are navigating from one screen to another screen .like back button and other button , it's seem look good when you are using navigation bar in your applicastion

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913332/navigationcontroller-navigationitem-vs-navigationitem.

Comment: @sandeeptomar my question is do they have different purposes ?

Comment: @Gamex wait ... *if u don't have navigation item or bar in Uiviewcontroller* well indeed there is no navigation bar in UIviewcontroller. Plus, changing the back button (or the toolbar) is the responsible of the ui navigation controller not uiviewcontroller, which is responsible just for its data, [read here please](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html)

Comment: @MartinR thank you, that links helped me understanding it. So if I want the `self.navigationController!.navigationItem.title = "test2"` I would need to embed the naviagtion controller into another naivagiont contoroller

Comment: @Sara what is the purpose for last comment ? self.title just sets title for current ViewController navigation item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that *all* `UIViewController`s have a `UINavigationItem`.

A `UINavigationController` decides what to show in its `navigationBar` by looking at the current viewController's navigationItem.

So you get this;

```
vcA.navigationItem.title = "A"
vcB.navigationItem.title = "B"

navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vcA)
// The title in the navigationBar is now "A"

navigationController.pushViewController(vcB, animated: true)
// The title in the navigationBar is now "B"
```

Since `UINavigationController` is also a subclass of `UIViewController`, it inherits the navigationItem as well, even though it's useless in most cases.

Comment: Would that be the same for toolBar? so uiviewController has a toolBar, and uINavigationController has toolBar

Answer (score 0):

One is

**"The nearest ancestor in the view controller hierarchy that is a navigation Controller"**

```
self.navigationController!.navigationItem.title = "test2"
```

[image]

The second type:

**"The navigation item used to represent the view controller in a parent's navigation bar"**
    self.navigationItem.title = "test"

[image]